# Backup folder issues

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, smo

When running the code below, I keep getting "access is denied", but i have full administrative rights on the folder.

`{"Cannot open backup device '\\\\networkDrive\backups\\'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).\r\nBACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally."}`

the folder target is @"\networkDrive\backups";

I've also tried @"C:\backups"\ and @"C:\backups"

```
    private static string publicConString = "server=myServer;Trusted_Connection=Yes;persist security info=False;connection timeout=120";
    public static void BackupDatabase(String databaseName, String userName, String password, String serverName, String destinationPath)
    {
        Backup sqlBackup = new Backup();

        sqlBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
        sqlBackup.BackupSetDescription = "ArchiveDataBase:" +
                                         DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        sqlBackup.BackupSetName = "Archive";

        sqlBackup.Database = databaseName;

        BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(destinationPath, DeviceType.File);
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(publicConString);
        ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(sqlCon);
        Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

        Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];

        sqlBackup.Initialize = true;
        sqlBackup.Checksum = true;
        sqlBackup.ContinueAfterError = true;

        sqlBackup.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
        sqlBackup.Incremental = false;

        sqlBackup.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
        //sqlBackup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;

        sqlBackup.FormatMedia = false;

        sqlBackup.SqlBackup(sqlServer);
```

Answer (score 3):

From your description, I think you would like to back up database to a network share folder, right?

Based on the error message, I think the SQL Server service account doesn’t have sufficient permission on the share folder. Please ensure the SQL Server service account is a domain account and it has sufficient permissions.

Please refer to this [info](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207187) for more information.

---

You cannot back up databases to a network drive if your account have not sufficient permissions to access the network drive.

Comment: To my understadning giving "Everyone" "Full Control" Should resolve this\